# A way to not have to reset the color/style in colorama every time

Tags: python, colors, colorama

Okay so I'm using Colorama for Python, and I'm making a text based RPG. I need to use the colors for many reasons, mainly for item "rarity" I guess. Is there a way to not have to reset the Fore/Style every single time I print colored text? I'm on Windows 10.

I guess an example would be

```
print(Fore.GREEN + "Welcome to my shop, here are my items...")
print("Generic item 1...")
```

But I don't want to have that second printed line be green, WITHOUT resetting it every time.

Comment: How about overwrite the print method or create your own "print" which reset the color?

Comment: REALLY make sure u never put the reset line in a loop. it slows down ur script by each iteration and took me a week to figure out :P

Answer (score 9):

From the colorama package [website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama),

> If you find yourself repeatedly sending reset sequences to turn off color changes at the end of every print, then init(autoreset=True) will automate that:

```
from colorama import init
init(autoreset=True)
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print('automatically back to default color again')
```

Comment: Then you will have to set the colour every time instead of resetting, if i am doing multiple lines in colour i would rather do one call to a colour then one call to a reset, rather than multiple colour calls

Answer (score 2):

Once you have changed the color of your output text it cannot go back to normal without actually resetting it back to normal.

So to further on from MK Ultra's comment I would suggest something like this;

```
def print_normal(string): #takes your string as input
    print(Fore.WHITE+Style.RESET_ALL+string) 
    #prints normal color and style text to the console
```

So then in your example code;

```
print(Fore.GREEN + "Welcome to my shop, here are my items...") #green text
print_normal("Generic item 1...") #normal text
```